# Meteor settings configuration for client when adding after boot

Tags: meteor

I am trying to deploy my Meteor app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. They don't support JSON objects as environment variables so there needs to be a workaround. I am uploading a `settings.json` file to `/tmp/settings.json` and saving the path as `process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE` then in a server file I do the following:

```
if (Meteor.isProduction) {
  var meteorFile = process.env.METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE;
  if(meteorFile == undefined) throw new Error(
    'METEOR_SETTINGS_FILE env variable must be defined in production.')
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var pjsonBuf = fs.readFileSync( meteorFile );
  Meteor.settings = JSON.parse( pjsonBuf.toString().trim());
  Meteor.settings.public = Meteor.settings.public;
}
```

However, on the client I still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeKey' of undefined` where undefined needs to be `Meteor.settings.public.segment`. I have an empty object as `Meteor.settings.public` and if I `console.log(Meteor.settings)` in the file above, they are all there.

Comment: use the below command to start meteor   <br> meteor --settings settings.json

Comment: That doesn't work, as you don't run 'meteor' on the production server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using environment variables:

Presumably Elastic Beanstalk allows you to specify environment variables, either in a shell script or in the config file. My example uses Nginx/Passenger.

```
# Tell the app where MongoDB is
passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/amba;
# Tell the app what its other settings are
passenger_env_var ROOT_URL https://dev1.amba.online;
passenger_env_var PEERJS_SERVER https://member2.myserver.com:9002/n5rdmnddd8q2z3q5mi;

passenger_env_var IMAGE_DIR /var/www/imgserver/public;
```

In the server, a meteor method reads the environment variables and inserts them into a table:

```
// Get a list of environment vars and put them in the Environs collection
// - client code will pick these up and handle them.
  getEnvirons: function() {
    Environs.remove({});    // Force them to be re-read every time
    var toGet = ["PEERJS_SERVER", "ROOT_URL", "IMAGE_DIR"];
    _.each(toGet, function(e){
      var val = process.env[e];
      Environs.insert({name: e, value: val});
    });
  },
```

Call the above from a Meteor startup block in the server.

All that remains to be done is to publish the Environs collection and subscribe to it. (I am assuming you know how to do that). The loading of the environment variable data will be asynchronous of course, so allow for that in your code